# Зависает IDEA при попытки открытия файла

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот это окно вылетает каждый раз, когда я через панельку слева (файловый менеджер проекта) пытаюсь (на дабл ЛКМ) открыть файл. Причём если Драгон-Дропом открывать, то всё нормально. Сначала замечал это на 2023.3 EAP, но сейчас началось и на выпуске 2023.2.3 возникать. Причём файлы не тяжёлые, там меньше 200 строк, и почти всё - статичные классы.

Убийство через диспетчер задач помогает только перезапустить редактор.

Comment: Включить выключить пробовали?)) (компьютер)

Comment: Пробовал даже розетку менять...

Comment: И диск от вирусов помыл